# Hosted, private or integrated web panel

Tags: java, networking, web, panel

I'm currently writing a Java program including a web panel. The program itself manages gameserver on a root/ vServer. The web panel is there to control the program and display information about the servers. The program uses sockets to communicate with the web panel.
 Now I'm getting to the point where I'll have to decide between **three possibilities**:

1. **Hosted web panel:** I'll host the web panel in on a webspace. Everybody who wants to use the web panel to manage their servers will have to visit a website to login to the web panel.
2. **Private web panel:** Every customer will have to upload the web folder including the web panel on his own webspace.
3. **Integrated web panel:** I'll integrate a Java webserver to my program which will host the web panel.

Which one is the best? Why? Are there any other options? Is this the right way to do something like this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3 seems the best one to me. Reason for this:

Solution 1: It might be rather difficult/slow to "talk" to the application, whereas with solution 3 you can do everything fast as it's on the same server. Also don't forget the risk of your webspace ever going down/being inaccessible.

Solution 2: Just don't do this as this complicates the setup for your customers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hosted web panel: That looks good but users are dependent on this server. So you would need to keep maintaining it and making sure it's up all the time.
2. This is related to the Solution 3. because both seems to be hosted on the users machine.
3. This is good especially if it's a script file that will start the server.

Personal opinion: I would go with the 3rd one, and also I would use Docker container to make everything transparent for the user.